# Fully-featured forum plugin

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I'm looking for a plugin recommendation.

I'm currently using bbPress to add a forums area to our website.

However, it has been deemed "disappointing" in terms of functionality.

Are there any forum plugins which have the following features?

- Easy image attachment (i.e. not like the bbPress GD add-on which uses the Media Library)
- Unread threads / mark as unread button
- Private messaging
- Quoting
- Rich text editor for new topics/replies

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SimplePress](http://simple-press.com/) currently is the best-featured forum plugin for WordPress.

Comment: I'm looking into this now ronald. Looks really good so far; not sure how I missed it!

Comment: What a plugin! Thoroughly impressed. It will take me roughly 18 years to style it, but that's cool. Thanks for making me aware of that Ronald :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bbPress](http://bbpress.org/), also from the Team of WordPress; but is not a fully-featured forum like vBulletin. Since version 2.* integrated bbPress very fine in WP, but not so much features. Also it is possible to add via plugins functions to an nice forum, but many work and not so much free plugins for your list of wishe; but possible.

Also you can [check an forum plugin](http://tomuse.com/wordpress-forum-plugin/), longer development, but the most of this with old source and not the possibilities of WordPress.

Another chance is to dev an custom forum plugin with custom post types and taxonomies, like [this example](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/07/16/a-wordpress-forum-plugin-using-custom-post-types).

Comment: Hi bueltge. As per my original post, I'm currently using bbPress but it lacks features. I've considered writing my own plugin but I suspect it would take me a huge amount of time. Surely something already exists? :)

Comment: yes, understand you - but i think current is not an existing result for your wishlist; better an fully featured forum from a forum dev group and a bridge/mapper for user from WP2Forum

Answer (score 0):

I hoped the "new" bbpress plugin would be better than the old standalone version :( 
Maybe you should create a custom post-type in wordpress and some plugins to create a kind of forum section for your wordpress site.

I abandoned bbpress a year ago and archived all forum posts on [finalwebsites.com](http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/) and added some form to my new wordpress blog. (PM me if you need more details)

Comment: It's still fairly featureless. The integration is nice and personally I would prefer to use it, but my partner and I come from an IPB background and he's adamant that he requires such functionality. Look to the answer of this thread Olaf - SimplePress is superb.